# Using Iterators to remove elements from a Java Collection

Tags: java, collections, iterator

There are many posts that suggest using Iterators to safely remove an element from a collection. Something like this:

```
Iterator<Book> i = books.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    if(i.next().isbn().equals(isbn)){
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

According to the documentation, the benefit of using an Iterator is that it is "fail fast" in the sense that if any thread is modifying the collection (books in the above example), while the iterator is used, then the iterator would throw a ConcurrentModificationException.
However, the documentation of this exception also says

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only to detect bugs.

Does this mean that using iterators is not an option if 100% correctness has to be guaranteed? Do I need to design my code in such a way that removal while the collection is modified would always result in correct behavior? If so, can anyone give an example where using the .remove() method of an iterator is useful outside of testing?

Comment: If there's only one thread that iterates over and modifies the collection, there's no problem with using the iterator's remove method.

Comment: Right. I guess this is the trivial scenario. But in a typical web environment you have multi threaded applications. This is the more interesting scenario. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Even in multi-threaded applications, many Collections would still be local to a single thread.

Comment: The benefit of using the iterator for removing is that it is *the correct way* of doing it, contrary to almost all alternatives. Whether the iterator has a fail-fast behavior is entirely irrelevant, iterators to concurrent collections are not fail-fast at all, still, removing through the iterator while iterating is correct. You have an entirely wrong understanding of the reason to use the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

`Iterator#remove` guarantees 100% correctness for single-threaded processing. In multi-threaded processing of data, it depends on how (synchronized/asynchronized processing, using a different list for collecting the elements to be removed etc.) you process the data.

As long as you do not want the same collection to be modified, you can collect the elements to be removed, into a separate `List` and use [`List#removeAll(Collection<?> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);

        List<Integer> elementsToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Integer i : list) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                elementsToBeRemoved.add(i);
            }
        }

        list.removeAll(elementsToBeRemoved);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3]
```

### In a loop, never remove elements using the index

For a beginner, it may be tempting to use [`List#remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) to remove the elements using index but the fact that every remove operation resizes the `List` makes it produce confusing results e.g.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new Vector<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("I'm inside the iterator loop.");
            i.next();
            list.remove(0);
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
I'm inside the iterator loop.
[2]
```

The reason for this output is depicted below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator.remove` will work as long as no other thread changes the Collection while you're iterating over it. Sometimes its a handy feature.

When it comes to multithreaded environment, it really depends on how do you organize the code.
For example if you create a collection inside a web request and do not share it with other requests (for example if it gets passed to some methods via method parameters) you can still safely use this method of traversing the collection.

On the other hand, if you have say a 'global' queue of metrics snapshots shared among all the requests, each request adds stats to this queue, and some other thread reads the queue elements and deletes the metrics, this way won't be appropriate.
So its all about the use case and the how do you organize the code.

As for the example that you're asking for, say you have a collection of Strings and would like to remove all the strings that start with a letter 'a' *by modifying the existing collection*

```
Iterator<String> i = strings.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    if(i.next().startsWith('a')){
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Of course in Java 8+ you can achieve *almost* the same with Streams:

```
strings.stream()
.filter(s -> !s.startsWith('a'))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, this method creates a new collection, rather than modifying the existing one (like in the case with iterators).

In pre java 8 world (and iterators have appeared way before java 8 was available), we don't even have streams, so code like this was not really straightforward task to write.

Comment: Those cases are not the same. The stream one creates a new collection, the iteration one modifies the old one. The equivalent iteration would be `List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(); for(String candidate : strings) if (filter(candidate) result.add(candidate);`.

Comment: @daniu, yes you're right, I've modified the answer to emphasize the difference.

Comment: When you want to use a Java 8 feature that can replace the manual iterator loop, use `strings.removeIf(s -> s.startsWith('a'));` That’s safe, more readable, and for some collections, it’s more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting piece of code (could be a good interview question). Would this program compile? And if so, would it run without exceptions?

```
List<Integer> list = new Vector<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    i.next();
    list.remove(0);
}
```

Answer : yes. It would compile and run without exceptions. That's because there are two remove methods for the list:

> **E   remove(int index)**
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation).

> **boolean     remove(Object o)**
> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation).

And the one that gets called is **boolean   remove(Object o)**. Since 0 is not in the list, the list is not modified, and there is no error. This doesn't mean that there's something wrong with the concept of an iterator, but it shows that, even in a single thread situation, just because an iterator is used, does not mean the developer cannot make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that using iterators is not an option if 100% correctness has to be guaranteed?

Not necessarily.

First of all, it depends on your criteria for correctness.  Correctness can only be measured against specified requirements.  Saying something is 100% correct is meaningless if you don't say what the requirements are.

There are also some generalizations that we can make.

1. If a collection (and its iterator) is used by one thread only, 100% correctness can be guaranteed.
2. A *concurrent* collection types can be safely accessed and updated via its iterators from any number of threads. There are some caveats though:

   - An iteration is not guaranteed to see structural changes made after the iteration starts.
   - An iterator is not designed to be shared by multiple threads.
   - Bulk operations on a `ConcurrentHashMap` are not atomic.

   If your correctness criteria do not depend one these things, then 100% correctness can be guaranteed.

Note: I'm not saying that iterators guarantee correctness.  I am saying that iterators can be part of a correct solution, assuming that you use them the right way.

> Do I need to design my code in such a way that removal while the collection is modified would always result in correct behavior?

It depends how you use the collection.  See above.

But as a general rule, you do need to *design* and *implement* you code to be correct.  (Correctness won't happen by magic ...)

> If so, can anyone give an example where using the `remove()` method of an iterator is useful outside of testing?

In any example where only one thread can access the collection, using `remove()` is 100% safe, for all standard collection classes.

In many examples where the collection is a concurrent type, `remove()` is 100% safe.  (But there is no guarantee that an element will *stay* removed if another thread is simultaneously trying to add it.  Or that it will be added for that matter.)

The bottom line is that if your application is multi-threaded, then you have to *understand* how different threads may interact with shared collections.  There is no way to avoid that.